# C#: Does not implement inherited abstract member with error when implement

Tags: c#, xamarin, bluetooth

I'm converting a .jar to .dll to use in my Xamarin C# project. This is a [lib](https://github.com/DantSu/ESCPOS-ThermalPrinter-Android) and when I try to compile, it gives me this error:

CS0534: Does not implement inherited abstract member

This error appears when I'm doing this conversion, following this [post](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/xamarin/android/platform/binding-java-library/binding-a-jar) here.

This is the page that is giving me the error:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
using Android.Runtime;
using Java.Interop;

namespace Com.Dantsu.Escposprinter.Connection.Bluetooth {

    // Metadata.xml XPath class reference: path="/api/package[@name='com.dantsu.escposprinter.connection.bluetooth']/class[@name='BluetoothConnection']"
    [global::Android.Runtime.Register ("com/dantsu/escposprinter/connection/bluetooth/BluetoothConnection", DoNotGenerateAcw=true)]
    public partial class BluetoothConnection : global::Com.Dantsu.Escposprinter.Connection.DeviceConnection {

        static readonly JniPeerMembers _members = new XAPeerMembers ("com/dantsu/escposprinter/connection/bluetooth/BluetoothConnection", typeof (BluetoothConnection));
        internal static new IntPtr class_ref {
            get {
                return _members.JniPeerType.PeerReference.Handle;
            }
        }

        public override global::Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers JniPeerMembers {
            get { return _members; }
        }

        protected override IntPtr ThresholdClass {
            get { return _members.JniPeerType.PeerReference.Handle; }
        }

        protected override global::System.Type ThresholdType {
            get { return _members.ManagedPeerType; }
        }

        protected BluetoothConnection (IntPtr javaReference, JniHandleOwnership transfer) : base (javaReference, transfer) {}

        // Metadata.xml XPath constructor reference: path="/api/package[@name='com.dantsu.escposprinter.connection.bluetooth']/class[@name='BluetoothConnection']/constructor[@name='BluetoothConnection' and count(parameter)=1 and parameter[1][@type='android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice']]"
        [Register (".ctor", "(Landroid/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice;)V", "")]
        public unsafe BluetoothConnection (global::Android.Bluetooth.BluetoothDevice device)
            : base (IntPtr.Zero, JniHandleOwnership.DoNotTransfer)
        {
            const string __id = "(Landroid/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice;)V";

            if (((global::Java.Lang.Object) this).Handle != IntPtr.Zero)
                return;

            try {
                JniArgumentValue* __args = stackalloc JniArgumentValue [1];
                __args [0] = new JniArgumentValue ((device == null) ? IntPtr.Zero : ((global::Java.Lang.Object) device).Handle);
                var __r = _members.InstanceMethods.StartCreateInstance (__id, ((object) this).GetType (), __args);
                SetHandle (__r.Handle, JniHandleOwnership.TransferLocalRef);
                _members.InstanceMethods.FinishCreateInstance (__id, this, __args);
            } finally {
                global::System.GC.KeepAlive (device);
            }
        }

        static Delegate cb_getDevice;
#pragma warning disable 0169
        static Delegate GetGetDeviceHandler ()
        {
            if (cb_getDevice == null)
                cb_getDevice = JNINativeWrapper.CreateDelegate ((_JniMarshal_PP_L) n_GetDevice);
            return cb_getDevice;
        }

        static IntPtr n_GetDevice (IntPtr jnienv, IntPtr native__this)
        {
            var __this = global::Java.Lang.Object.GetObject<global::Com.Dantsu.Escposprinter.Connection.Bluetooth.BluetoothConnection> (jnienv, native__this, JniHandleOwnership.DoNotTransfer);
            return JNIEnv.ToLocalJniHandle (__this.Device);
        }
#pragma warning restore 0169

        public virtual unsafe global::Android.Bluetooth.BluetoothDevice Device {
            // Metadata.xml XPath method reference: path="/api/package[@name='com.dantsu.escposprinter.connection.bluetooth']/class[@name='BluetoothConnection']/method[@name='getDevice' and count(parameter)=0]"
            [Register ("getDevice", "()Landroid/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice;", "GetGetDeviceHandler")]
            get {
                const string __id = "getDevice.()Landroid/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice;";
                try {
                    var __rm = _members.InstanceMethods.InvokeVirtualObjectMethod (__id, this, null);
                    return global::Java.Lang.Object.GetObject<global::Android.Bluetooth.BluetoothDevice> (__rm.Handle, JniHandleOwnership.TransferLocalRef);
                } finally {
                }
            }
        }

        static Delegate cb_connect;
#pragma warning disable 0169
        static Delegate GetConnectHandler ()
        {
            if (cb_connect == null)
                cb_connect = JNINativeWrapper.CreateDelegate ((_JniMarshal_PP_L) n_Connect);
            return cb_connect;
        }

        static IntPtr n_Connect (IntPtr jnienv, IntPtr native__this)
        {
            var __this = global::Java.Lang.Object.GetObject<global::Com.Dantsu.Escposprinter.Connection.Bluetooth.BluetoothConnection> (jnienv, native__this, JniHandleOwnership.DoNotTransfer);
            return JNIEnv.ToLocalJniHandle (__this.Connect ());
        }
#pragma warning restore 0169

        // Metadata.xml XPath method reference: path="/api/package[@name='com.dantsu.escposprinter.connection.bluetooth']/class[@name='BluetoothConnection']/method[@name='connect' and count(parameter)=0]"
        [Register ("connect", "()Lcom/dantsu/escposprinter/connection/bluetooth/BluetoothConnection;", "GetConnectHandler")]
        public virtual unsafe global::Com.Dantsu.Escposprinter.Connection.Bluetooth.BluetoothConnection Connect ()
        {
            const string __id = "connect.()Lcom/dantsu/escposprinter/connection/bluetooth/BluetoothConnection;";
            try {
                var __rm = _members.InstanceMethods.InvokeVirtualObjectMethod (__id, this, null);
                return global::Java.Lang.Object.GetObject<global::Com.Dantsu.Escposprinter.Connection.Bluetooth.BluetoothConnection> (__rm.Handle, JniHandleOwnership.TransferLocalRef);
            } finally {
            }
        }

        static Delegate cb_disconnect;
#pragma warning disable 0169
        static Delegate GetDisconnectHandler ()
        {
            if (cb_disconnect == null)
                cb_disconnect = JNINativeWrapper.CreateDelegate ((_JniMarshal_PP_L) n_Disconnect);
            return cb_disconnect;
        }

        static IntPtr n_Disconnect (IntPtr jnienv, IntPtr native__this)
        {
            var __this = global::Java.Lang.Object.GetObject<global::Com.Dantsu.Escposprinter.Connection.Bluetooth.BluetoothConnection> (jnienv, native__this, JniHandleOwnership.DoNotTransfer);
            return JNIEnv.ToLocalJniHandle (__this.Disconnect ());
        }
#pragma warning restore 0169

        // Metadata.xml XPath method reference: path="/api/package[@name='com.dantsu.escposprinter.connection.bluetooth']/class[@name='BluetoothConnection']/method[@name='disconnect' and count(parameter)=0]"
        [Register ("disconnect", "()Lcom/dantsu/escposprinter/connection/bluetooth/BluetoothConnection;", "GetDisconnectHandler")]
        public virtual unsafe global::Com.Dantsu.Escposprinter.Connection.Bluetooth.BluetoothConnection Disconnect ()
        {
            const string __id = "disconnect.()Lcom/dantsu/escposprinter/connection/bluetooth/BluetoothConnection;";
            try {
                var __rm = _members.InstanceMethods.InvokeVirtualObjectMethod (__id, this, null);
                return global::Java.Lang.Object.GetObject<global::Com.Dantsu.Escposprinter.Connection.Bluetooth.BluetoothConnection> (__rm.Handle, JniHandleOwnership.TransferLocalRef);
            } finally {
            }
        }

    }
}
```

so, if I go to the inherited `global::Com.Dantsu.Escposprinter.Connection.DeviceConnection`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Android.Runtime;
using Java.Interop;

namespace Com.Dantsu.Escposprinter.Connection {

    // Metadata.xml XPath class reference: path="/api/package[@name='com.dantsu.escposprinter.connection']/class[@name='DeviceConnection']"
    [global::Android.Runtime.Register ("com/dantsu/escposprinter/connection/DeviceConnection", DoNotGenerateAcw=true)]
    public abstract partial class DeviceConnection : global::Java.Lang.Object {



        // Metadata.xml XPath field reference: path="/api/package[@name='com.dantsu.escposprinter.connection']/class[@name='DeviceConnection']/field[@name='data']"
        [Register ("data")]
        protected IList<byte> Data {
            get {
                const string __id = "data.[B";

                var __v = _members.InstanceFields.GetObjectValue (__id, this);
                return global::Android.Runtime.JavaArray<byte>.FromJniHandle (__v.Handle, JniHandleOwnership.TransferLocalRef);
            }
            set {
                const string __id = "data.[B";

                IntPtr native_value = global::Android.Runtime.JavaArray<byte>.ToLocalJniHandle (value);
                try {
                    _members.InstanceFields.SetValue (__id, this, new JniObjectReference (native_value));
                } finally {
                    global::Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.DeleteLocalRef (native_value);
                }
            }
        }


        // Metadata.xml XPath field reference: path="/api/package[@name='com.dantsu.escposprinter.connection']/class[@name='DeviceConnection']/field[@name='stream']"
        [Register ("stream")]
        protected global::System.IO.Stream Stream {
            get {
                const string __id = "stream.Ljava/io/OutputStream;";

                var __v = _members.InstanceFields.GetObjectValue (__id, this);
                return global::Android.Runtime.OutputStreamInvoker.FromJniHandle (__v.Handle, JniHandleOwnership.TransferLocalRef);
            }
            set {
                const string __id = "stream.Ljava/io/OutputStream;";

                IntPtr native_value = global::Android.Runtime.OutputStreamAdapter.ToLocalJniHandle (value);
                try {
                    _members.InstanceFields.SetValue (__id, this, new JniObjectReference (native_value));
                } finally {
                    JNIEnv.DeleteLocalRef (native_value);
                }
            }
        }
        static readonly JniPeerMembers _members = new XAPeerMembers ("com/dantsu/escposprinter/connection/DeviceConnection", typeof (DeviceConnection));
        internal static IntPtr class_ref {
            get {
                return _members.JniPeerType.PeerReference.Handle;
            }
        }

        public override global::Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers JniPeerMembers {
            get { return _members; }
        }

        protected override IntPtr ThresholdClass {
            get { return _members.JniPeerType.PeerReference.Handle; }
        }

        protected override global::System.Type ThresholdType {
            get { return _members.ManagedPeerType; }
        }

        protected DeviceConnection (IntPtr javaReference, JniHandleOwnership transfer) : base (javaReference, transfer) {}

        // Metadata.xml XPath constructor reference: path="/api/package[@name='com.dantsu.escposprinter.connection']/class[@name='DeviceConnection']/constructor[@name='DeviceConnection' and count(parameter)=0]"
        [Register (".ctor", "()V", "")]
        public unsafe DeviceConnection ()
            : base (IntPtr.Zero, JniHandleOwnership.DoNotTransfer)
        {
            const string __id = "()V";

            if (((global::Java.Lang.Object) this).Handle != IntPtr.Zero)
                return;

            try {
                var __r = _members.InstanceMethods.StartCreateInstance (__id, ((object) this).GetType (), null);
                SetHandle (__r.Handle, JniHandleOwnership.TransferLocalRef);
                _members.InstanceMethods.FinishCreateInstance (__id, this, null);
            } finally {
            }
        }

        static Delegate cb_isConnected;
#pragma warning disable 0169
        static Delegate GetIsConnectedHandler ()
        {
            if (cb_isConnected == null)
                cb_isConnected = JNINativeWrapper.CreateDelegate ((_JniMarshal_PP_Z) n_IsConnected);
            return cb_isConnected;
        }

        static bool n_IsConnected (IntPtr jnienv, IntPtr native__this)
        {
            var __this = global::Java.Lang.Object.GetObject<global::Com.Dantsu.Escposprinter.Connection.DeviceConnection> (jnienv, native__this, JniHandleOwnership.DoNotTransfer);
            return __this.IsConnected;
        }
#pragma warning restore 0169

        public virtual unsafe bool IsConnected {
            // Metadata.xml XPath method reference: path="/api/package[@name='com.dantsu.escposprinter.connection']/class[@name='DeviceConnection']/method[@name='isConnected' and count(parameter)=0]"
            [Register ("isConnected", "()Z", "GetIsConnectedHandler")]
            get {
                const string __id = "isConnected.()Z";
                try {
                    var __rm = _members.InstanceMethods.InvokeVirtualBooleanMethod (__id, this, null);
                    return __rm;
                } finally {
                }
            }
        }

        static Delegate cb_connect;
#pragma warning disable 0169
        static Delegate GetConnectHandler ()
        {
            if (cb_connect == null)
                cb_connect = JNINativeWrapper.CreateDelegate ((_JniMarshal_PP_L) n_Connect);
            return cb_connect;
        }

        static IntPtr n_Connect (IntPtr jnienv, IntPtr native__this)
        {
            var __this = global::Java.Lang.Object.GetObject<global::Com.Dantsu.Escposprinter.Connection.DeviceConnection> (jnienv, native__this, JniHandleOwnership.DoNotTransfer);
            return JNIEnv.ToLocalJniHandle (__this.Connect ());
        }
#pragma warning restore 0169

        // Metadata.xml XPath method reference: path="/api/package[@name='com.dantsu.escposprinter.connection']/class[@name='DeviceConnection']/method[@name='connect' and count(parameter)=0]"
        [Register ("connect", "()Lcom/dantsu/escposprinter/connection/DeviceConnection;", "GetConnectHandler")]
        public abstract global::Com.Dantsu.Escposprinter.Connection.DeviceConnection Connect ();

        static Delegate cb_disconnect;
#pragma warning disable 0169
        static Delegate GetDisconnectHandler ()
        {
            if (cb_disconnect == null)
                cb_disconnect = JNINativeWrapper.CreateDelegate ((_JniMarshal_PP_L) n_Disconnect);
            return cb_disconnect;
        }

        static IntPtr n_Disconnect (IntPtr jnienv, IntPtr native__this)
        {
            var __this = global::Java.Lang.Object.GetObject<global::Com.Dantsu.Escposprinter.Connection.DeviceConnection> (jnienv, native__this, JniHandleOwnership.DoNotTransfer);
            return JNIEnv.ToLocalJniHandle (__this.Disconnect ());
        }
#pragma warning restore 0169

        // Metadata.xml XPath method reference: path="/api/package[@name='com.dantsu.escposprinter.connection']/class[@name='DeviceConnection']/method[@name='disconnect' and count(parameter)=0]"
        [Register ("disconnect", "()Lcom/dantsu/escposprinter/connection/DeviceConnection;", "GetDisconnectHandler")]
        public abstract global::Com.Dantsu.Escposprinter.Connection.DeviceConnection Disconnect ();

        static Delegate cb_send;
#pragma warning disable 0169
        static Delegate GetSendHandler ()
        {
            if (cb_send == null)
                cb_send = JNINativeWrapper.CreateDelegate ((_JniMarshal_PP_V) n_Send);
            return cb_send;
        }

        static void n_Send (IntPtr jnienv, IntPtr native__this)
        {
            var __this = global::Java.Lang.Object.GetObject<global::Com.Dantsu.Escposprinter.Connection.DeviceConnection> (jnienv, native__this, JniHandleOwnership.DoNotTransfer);
            __this.Send ();
        }
#pragma warning restore 0169

        // Metadata.xml XPath method reference: path="/api/package[@name='com.dantsu.escposprinter.connection']/class[@name='DeviceConnection']/method[@name='send' and count(parameter)=0]"
        [Register ("send", "()V", "GetSendHandler")]
        public virtual unsafe void Send ()
        {
            const string __id = "send.()V";
            try {
                _members.InstanceMethods.InvokeVirtualVoidMethod (__id, this, null);
            } finally {
            }
        }

        static Delegate cb_send_I;
#pragma warning disable 0169
        static Delegate GetSend_IHandler ()
        {
            if (cb_send_I == null)
                cb_send_I = JNINativeWrapper.CreateDelegate ((_JniMarshal_PPI_V) n_Send_I);
            return cb_send_I;
        }

        static void n_Send_I (IntPtr jnienv, IntPtr native__this, int addWaitingTime)
        {
            var __this = global::Java.Lang.Object.GetObject<global::Com.Dantsu.Escposprinter.Connection.DeviceConnection> (jnienv, native__this, JniHandleOwnership.DoNotTransfer);
            __this.Send (addWaitingTime);
        }
#pragma warning restore 0169

        // Metadata.xml XPath method reference: path="/api/package[@name='com.dantsu.escposprinter.connection']/class[@name='DeviceConnection']/method[@name='send' and count(parameter)=1 and parameter[1][@type='int']]"
        [Register ("send", "(I)V", "GetSend_IHandler")]
        public virtual unsafe void Send (int addWaitingTime)
        {
            const string __id = "send.(I)V";
            try {
                JniArgumentValue* __args = stackalloc JniArgumentValue [1];
                __args [0] = new JniArgumentValue (addWaitingTime);
                _members.InstanceMethods.InvokeVirtualVoidMethod (__id, this, __args);
            } finally {
            }
        }

        static Delegate cb_write_arrayB;
#pragma warning disable 0169
        static Delegate GetWrite_arrayBHandler ()
        {
            if (cb_write_arrayB == null)
                cb_write_arrayB = JNINativeWrapper.CreateDelegate ((_JniMarshal_PPL_V) n_Write_arrayB);
            return cb_write_arrayB;
        }

        static void n_Write_arrayB (IntPtr jnienv, IntPtr native__this, IntPtr native_bytes)
        {
            var __this = global::Java.Lang.Object.GetObject<global::Com.Dantsu.Escposprinter.Connection.DeviceConnection> (jnienv, native__this, JniHandleOwnership.DoNotTransfer);
            var bytes = (byte[]) JNIEnv.GetArray (native_bytes, JniHandleOwnership.DoNotTransfer, typeof (byte));
            __this.Write (bytes);
            if (bytes != null)
                JNIEnv.CopyArray (bytes, native_bytes);
        }
#pragma warning restore 0169

        // Metadata.xml XPath method reference: path="/api/package[@name='com.dantsu.escposprinter.connection']/class[@name='DeviceConnection']/method[@name='write' and count(parameter)=1 and parameter[1][@type='byte[]']]"
        [Register ("write", "([B)V", "GetWrite_arrayBHandler")]
        public virtual unsafe void Write (byte[] bytes)
        {
            const string __id = "write.([B)V";
            IntPtr native_bytes = JNIEnv.NewArray (bytes);
            try {
                JniArgumentValue* __args = stackalloc JniArgumentValue [1];
                __args [0] = new JniArgumentValue (native_bytes);
                _members.InstanceMethods.InvokeVirtualVoidMethod (__id, this, __args);
            } finally {
                if (bytes != null) {
                    JNIEnv.CopyArray (native_bytes, bytes);
                    JNIEnv.DeleteLocalRef (native_bytes);
                }
                global::System.GC.KeepAlive (bytes);
            }
        }

    }

    [global::Android.Runtime.Register ("com/dantsu/escposprinter/connection/DeviceConnection", DoNotGenerateAcw=true)]
    internal partial class DeviceConnectionInvoker : DeviceConnection {

        public DeviceConnectionInvoker (IntPtr handle, JniHandleOwnership transfer) : base (handle, transfer) {}

        static readonly JniPeerMembers _members = new XAPeerMembers ("com/dantsu/escposprinter/connection/DeviceConnection", typeof (DeviceConnectionInvoker));

        public override global::Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers JniPeerMembers {
            get { return _members; }
        }

        protected override global::System.Type ThresholdType {
            get { return _members.ManagedPeerType; }
        }

        // Metadata.xml XPath method reference: path="/api/package[@name='com.dantsu.escposprinter.connection']/class[@name='DeviceConnection']/method[@name='connect' and count(parameter)=0]"
        [Register ("connect", "()Lcom/dantsu/escposprinter/connection/DeviceConnection;", "GetConnectHandler")]
        public override unsafe global::Com.Dantsu.Escposprinter.Connection.DeviceConnection Connect ()
        {
            const string __id = "connect.()Lcom/dantsu/escposprinter/connection/DeviceConnection;";
            try {
                var __rm = _members.InstanceMethods.InvokeAbstractObjectMethod (__id, this, null);
                return global::Java.Lang.Object.GetObject<global::Com.Dantsu.Escposprinter.Connection.DeviceConnection> (__rm.Handle, JniHandleOwnership.TransferLocalRef);
            } finally {
            }
        }

        // Metadata.xml XPath method reference: path="/api/package[@name='com.dantsu.escposprinter.connection']/class[@name='DeviceConnection']/method[@name='disconnect' and count(parameter)=0]"
        [Register ("disconnect", "()Lcom/dantsu/escposprinter/connection/DeviceConnection;", "GetDisconnectHandler")]
        public override unsafe global::Com.Dantsu.Escposprinter.Connection.DeviceConnection Disconnect ()
        {
            const string __id = "disconnect.()Lcom/dantsu/escposprinter/connection/DeviceConnection;";
            try {
                var __rm = _members.InstanceMethods.InvokeAbstractObjectMethod (__id, this, null);
                return global::Java.Lang.Object.GetObject<global::Com.Dantsu.Escposprinter.Connection.DeviceConnection> (__rm.Handle, JniHandleOwnership.TransferLocalRef);
            } finally {
            }
        }

    }

}
```

This could be simple: I just implement the two methods and it's ok, but when I do it:

CS0111: type "BluetoothConnection" already defines a member called "Connect" with the same parameter types.

CS0111: type "BluetoothConnection" already defines a member called "Disconnect" with the same parameter types.

It's telling that is not implemented, but when I implement, it says that is already implemented.

I'm confused.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Did you use 'override' keyword when implementing the abstract member?

Comment: @AlexeyAdadurov yes, but it's saying that I have another `Connect` and `Disconnect` class already. In fact, it has: `public abstract global::Com.Dantsu.Escposprinter.Connection.DeviceConnection Connect ();`. It's in the code.

Comment: Please review [MCVE] guidance on posting code and [edit] the question to actually have only relevant code (and not wall of code).

Comment: Try updating your kernel : https://source.android.com/devices/architecture/kernel/android-common